# combobox inserting consecutive variables

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a question about combobox.I use visual c# and I want to insert consecutive numbers (1 to 100) in combobox.How can I do this?

Comment: WinForms? ASP.Net? WPF? Silverlight? What version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    comboBox.Items.Add(i + 1);
}
```

You can also use LINQ:

```
comboBox.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
```

Comment: I used the loop code .It worked first but then I deleted the variables written before by me, at that time it did not show the new inserted variables.